# datastructure in C++ for maintaining the insertion order and eliminating duplicates

Tags: c++

i need to maintain the order in which user entered the data, but need to eliminate the duplicates. I looked at map, it eliminates the duplicates, but it is not possible to maintain the order in which user entered. Same problem with set. Is there any datastructure in stl that can meet both the requirements? I cannot use boost on this project.

Comment: what do you mean the same with set? set is ordered.

Comment: @texasbruce: set is the same as map where it does not maintain the order of insertion.

Comment: How many elements? 10s? 1000s? 1000000s? 100000000s?  10000000000s?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a data structure that doesn't allow duplicates and also maintains order of entry?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808215/is-there-a-data-structure-that-doesnt-allow-duplicates-and-also-maintains-order)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that if you maintain search order, it's expensive to search for duplicates, so you don't tend to find data structures that do both.  C++11 introduces `std::unordered_set`, which is probably what you want.

If you don't use C++11, you can just encapsulate some standard containers in a class.  I would suggest that you pop your items into a `set` or a `map`, and then store an iterator to the item in a `vector`.

Answer (score 1):

Maintain a map and a list. For each element, search the map before appending to the list. If not found, append to the list and insert into the map, else continue.

Comment: Can you pls point me to an example, where i can specify a custom comparator for specifying when instances of my class should be equal?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "equal".  If order is unimportant, then compare the `map` (or `set`).  If order is important, compare the `list` (or `vector`).

Comment: @Jimm just provide your own operator overloads for ==, <, >.

Comment: Instead of map and list, I'd say unordered_set and vector.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> data;
    std::unordered_set<int> uniqueCollection;

    for(int i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
    {
        int newData = rand() % 27;

        cout << "trying to insert: " << newData << endl;

        if(uniqueCollection.find(newData) == uniqueCollection.end())
        {
            cout << "  inserting item: " << newData << endl;

            data.push_back(newData);    
            uniqueCollection.insert(newData);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "  element already exists: " << newData << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_set/

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/