# Easy. Fast way to compare two 800k each elements arrays

Tags: c++

Using mt19937_64 generator I generate 800 000 integers in the range from 0 to 30 000 000. Every number must be unique, so I ought to compare it to every already generated integer:

```
unsigned array[800 000]; 
for (int i = 0; i < 800 000; i++)
  {
    generate_again:      
    buffer = uid(rng); // generate in buffer

    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) // *comparing to every already generated integer
      {
        if (buffer == array[j])
          goto generate_again; // if the same integer exist, go togenerate_again flag
      }
      array[i] = pepper; // is integer is unique - it goes to array.
  }
```

This comparsion takes about 16 minutes. How can I do it faster? Thanks.

Comment: You can try to store generated numbers in a hash table for quick duplicate checking.

Comment: Please indent your code properly. This is nearly illegible

Comment: what's "30kk"? What did you expect?

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot I highly doubt that using any other hash than the integer itself would be more efficient.

Comment: @MarcusMüller less bucket size = less comparisons. If you would allocate 30kk bool array, comparison would be O(1)

Comment: whatever that means, @Revolver_Ocelot; most hash tables on mashines use the native int type as hash type, because that's the fastest thing to use in lookups.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I made it a bit more illegible, sorry. Somehow spaces gone crazy

Comment: @MarcusMüller hash type have no relation to data type or lookup speed. Arrays use native int type as index, but finding specific element is O(N) instead of amortized O(1) of hash tables

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot: Point is that you're right, you should use some kind of sorted container, but you're wrong, using a hash table is wrong for something that would be its own hash. Table lookups get faster if you use optimized code for comparison; modern compilers and standard runtimes do that; you get SIMD based comparisons that, for example, can compare 4 32bit ints at once, greatly increasing speed to go through the data structure.

Comment: Does that really compile? `800 000` doesn't look like a C++ numeric literal to me...

Comment: Also, be a bit careful with as what you "sell" this array: The result has, mathematically speaking, not the same distribution as your original random number generator!

Comment: @MarcusMüller Using a hash table for integers is not wrong. Radix sort, being faster than any general purpose sort for integers works by essentually inserting all integers in hash table then by sorting smaller buckets.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot: It *is* superfluous to hash something that is not harder to compare/sort than the hashes. That's all I'm saying :) In fact, many hash implementations just use the int itself as hash.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot now, using a key/value container with key == value does sound a bit strange, doesn't it? I'd guess you'd just use the heap or whatever structure is used to keep the keys, and drop the value storage part.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Hash tables are not always key-value containers. `std::unordered_set` is a hash table. I would expect either a no-op or really cheap hash (often byte-swapping first and second halves of number). The main idea is to limit amount of numbers you need to compare newly generated number with. Usually it is done by storing number in one or other place depending on some property: exactly what hash table does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first generate the unique numbers in order and then shuffle them to obtain the final result (if you need that at all).

Using [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) would be an efficient way to store if the value has already been generated. Alternatively, if you don't actually know the number of values at compile time, you could use [`std::vector<bool>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) which is a specialization using bit operations will also save you some space.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <bitset>


int main()
{
    static constexpr int max_value = 30'000'000;
    static constexpr int n_values = 800'000;

    std::bitset<max_value + 1> have_num;

    int cur_n_values = 0;

    std::mt19937_64 mt{std::random_device{}()};
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution{0, max_value};


    while (cur_n_values != n_values) {
        auto newVal = distribution(mt);

        if (!have_num[newVal]) {
            have_num[newVal] = true;
            ++cur_n_values;
        }
    }

    std::vector<int> nums;
    nums.reserve(n_values);

    for (int i = 0; i < have_num.size(); ++i) {
        if (have_num[i]) {
            nums.push_back(i);
        }
    }

    std::shuffle(nums.begin(), nums.end(), mt);

    for (auto i : nums) {
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }
}
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/ENXJ66435)

Comment: Bottom line is, identity is a perfectly valid hash function for integers.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to generate arrays, then check uniqueness and remove elements - store only unique numbers.

Try to use `hashed_unique` [boost::multiindex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/indices.html).
If you want to preserve order, make use of `ordered_unique`.

See also: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/769161/1566267)

Answer (score 1):

First of all eliminate check by cycling through array. If you only have 30E6 variants you can try put them in one array of boolean flags if you have enough space. That would cost about 30Mb. Another optimization by memory may be packing flags to bitmask. That would cost 8 times less. And it will improve speed. So having 30Mb/8 (~4Mb) sized array of flags you can check existence of already generated number in constant time. That wiil improve speed drastically. But there is another problem: having many generations you will stuck in repeated collisions.

Comment: Anton, would you kindly repeat you answer here: http://tinyurl.com/h9opzow (ru.stackoverflow) It will improve my understanding, because I got the idea, but not fully.